# C - Eliminating Loop Stutter?

Tags: c

I am making a little game using getch and print, as a bit of a test for myself, and surprisingly it actually works quite well but i'm having a bit of an issue. I am printing all of the tiles using a loop and printf, and of course as the loop has to process a bit, everytime the character moves, it re-prints everything, which causes a bit of a stutter, due to the loop printing. What can I possibly do to combat this?

This is how the tiles are printed

```
void Game() {
int X = 0;
int Y = 0;
int PrintWall = 0;
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        X = i;
        PrintWall = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                if (X == WallX[j]) {
                    if (Y == WallY[j]) {
                        PrintWall = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        if (X == Player.XCoor && Y == NegativeToPositive(Player.YCoor)) {
            printf("@");
        }

        else if (PrintWall == 1){
            printf("#");
        }

        else {
            printf(".");
        }
    }
    Y++;
} while (Y != 22);
```

}

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "stutter"? Is this the time it takes to draw the next frame?

Comment: Yes, as I am drawing everything with a loop and printf, whenever the character moves, it clears the screen and draws everything again, thus if you look at the bottom, it'll be blank for a few milliseconds, and whenever you move it gives this very blinding stutter effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try building the full screen of data into a buffer first and THEN print it. Start with an array of characters as long as you need it to be:

```
char buffer[SIZE_X * SIZE_Y];
```

Then go through your loop above, but instead of using `printf()`, set the character at that location in the buffer to what you want it to be:

```
buffer[(SIZE_X * Y) + X] = /* '@', '#', or '.' as appropriate */
```

Then, once you are through the loop, you will print the whole buffer to the screen:

```
printf(buffer);
```

Just make sure you don't accidentally overwrite your null terminator with another character or you may get more text than you bargained for.

Comment: Your fix does make it a lot better yet it still does stutter, any way to improve upon this?

Comment: Beyond this would be to follow the other ideas here. Namely updating only the characters that change by using your OS's own text cursor functions, or learn a library like ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

That is just a limitation of printing the whole "board" on every change. The only way to fix it is to only print what changes. Depending on your OS etc you may be able to print individual characters or lines instead of the whole board.

You could look at a library like curses to give character level control (there may be something better - don't know, I don't do this often enough to know ;-)

As other answers have said, printing in bigger pieces (like a whole buffer at a time) is better than `printf` for each individual character but you will still probably have the same issue but it is certainly worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Consider separating initialization and the game loop. Draw the game board as init and update everything in your do-while-loop.

You should limit the number of moving walls.
If a wall moves, you delete/replace the wall mark # at the old position, write out the mark on your interface at the new place and then change the mark's data in the arrays.

After that, you just check, if the new player position hits an obstacle. If no, delete/replace the current mark of the player with the default character and write the new position.
If the two players hit each other, you would need your old condition.